# Trying to detect system sound volume

Tags: c++, audio, detection, volume, detect

I'm writing a game for windows in c++ and want some of the sprites to move along with the music. I'm using SDL2 for the graphics and SDL2 mixer to play the music. I basically just am looking for a function that detects the current volume being sent to the speakers (so that I can try and set some threshold for when a "beat" happens), but all i can find is functions that detect the current volume "setting." I'm sure this is really easy to do, but I just can't find anything on it. Also, I don't care whether or not it detects sounds from other programs or anything like that.

Comment: while you could most probably detect that, what about users that simply have set the volume down through hardware ?

Comment: I'm really concerned about that. I'll probably have a condition where they move randomly if the sound is below a certain threshold. They're just background tiles in the game.

Comment: As you can't work around that technically (you will never be able to determinate the threshold... the user might even not have any speaker at all), you should maybe just inform the user that sound is important. That said, I'll let the people with more technical knowledge answer your question, that was just "my 2 cents" :-)

Comment: Yeah, I do have a function that detects whether anything is plugged in though. Thanks though!